# Question regarding SVN - " read-only working copy "

Tags: svn, web-applications

The web page says "Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP."

But it's a large web application (java pet store).

So this means I can't do anything except read/view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit it on your local system.  You can compile it, change it, play with it all you want.    You just can't check in changes to the repository.

It's "read-only" from the perspective of the repository only.

Answer (score -2):

download and compile calculator: http://digital-calculator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/